# Computation timed out when exporting time series for a large number of locations from Google Earth Engine

Tags: ndvi, sentinel-2, time-series, memory

I am trying to export Sentinel-2 NDVI time series for a huge number of fields (n>80000) to a csv file. However I got a 'computation timed out' error after 12 hours of running. Here is the code and also the [code link][1]. How can I improve this code so that it can fit in memory?

````
var polys = ee.FeatureCollection(table);
//Map.addLayer(polys, {color: 'red'}, 'Field Locations');

var polys = polys.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'id': feature.get('OBJECTID')})
}) // indicate a unique id for each field

var maskCloudsS2 = function(image) {
  var quality = image.select('SCL');
  var blueBand = image.select('B2');    // blue band of Sentinel-2 to mask additional cloud shadows
  var cloud = quality.lte(1).or(quality.eq(3)).or(quality.eq(7)).or(quality.eq(8)).or(quality.eq(9)).or(quality.eq(11)).or(blueBand.lt(100));
  // add a small buffer
  var cloudMask = cloud.fastDistanceTransform(2,"pixels","squared_euclidean").gt(0.5);
  var mask = cloudMask.not();
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask);
};

var addVI_S2 = function(image) {
  return image
    // Define functions for adding NDVI and EVI
    // Note reflectance data is scaled to 10000, EVI formula needs +10000 instead of +1
    // Add an NDVI band.
    .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')).float()
    // Add and EVI band.
    .addBands(image.expression(
      '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 10000))', {
        'NIR': image.select('B8'),
        'RED': image.select('B4'),
        'BLUE': image.select('B2')
      }).rename('EVI')).float();
};

// This field contains UNIX time in milliseconds.
var startDate = '2018-01-01';
var endDate = '2018-12-31';
var timeField = 'system:time_start';
var addTime = function(image) {
  // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
    var date = ee.Date(image.get(timeField));
    var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1980-01-01'), 'year');
    // Compute DOY
    var doy = date.getRelative('day', 'year');   // note that 0 = 1 January it seems!
  // Return the image with the added bands.
  return image
    // Add a time band.
    .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t').float())
    .addBands(ee.Image(doy).rename('doy').short());
    // Add a constant band.
      //.addBands(ee.Image.constant(1));
};

var S2l2a = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
      .filterBounds(polys)
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .map(addTime)
      .map(addVI_S2).map(maskCloudsS2)
      // Cast extra bands that are not to use
      .select(['B2', 'B4', 'B8', 'SCL', 'NDVI', 'EVI','t','doy']);
//print(S2l2a); 
  
// Export time series for all maize fields to a csv file
var triplets = S2l2a.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('NDVI').reduceRegions({
    collection: polys, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['NDVI']), 
    scale: 10,
//    tileScale: 4,
  })
    .map(function(feature) {
    var NDVI = ee.List([feature.get('NDVI'), -9999])
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
    return feature.set({'NDVI': NDVI, 'imageID': image.id()}).setGeometry(null);
    });
  }).flatten();

var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId); 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
        
  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          return [feature.get(colId), feature.get('NDVI')];
        });
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};
var sentinelResults = format(triplets, 'id','imageID');

// There are multiple image granules for the same date processed from the same orbit
// Granules overlap with each other and since they are processed independently
// the pixel values can differ slightly. So the same pixel can have different NDVI 
// values for the same date from overlapping granules.
// So to simplify the output, observations are merged for each day
// by taking the max VIs value from overlapping observations
var merge = function(table, rowId) {
  return table.map(function(feature) {
    var id = feature.get(rowId);
    var allKeys = feature.toDictionary().keys().remove(rowId);
    var substrKeys = ee.List(allKeys.map(function(val) { 
        return ee.String(val).slice(0,8)}
        ));
    var uniqueKeys = substrKeys.distinct();
    var pairs = uniqueKeys.map(function(key) {
      var matches = feature.toDictionary().select(allKeys.filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('item', key))).values();
      var val = matches.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
      return [key, val];
    });
    return feature.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(pairs.flatten()));
  });
};
var sentinelMerged = merge(sentinelResults, 'id');

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: sentinelMerged,
    description: 'NDVItimeSeries',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'NDVItimeSeries',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
  
    ```


  [1]: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8542c755a7775505a4dd37df24bd73a0?hideCode=true
````

Comment: I ran into similar problems. Do you find any solutions or improvements so far?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to split the polygon layer into multiple chunks then combine the results.  I have a similar process and can only process a few thousand of my >60,000 shapefile at a time.

Also, you probably need to change the order with which you map things in your composting step:

```
var S2l2a = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
      .filterBounds(polys)
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .map(addTime)
      .map(addVI_S2).map(maskCloudsS2)
```

is going to calculate your spectral index 'VI' before you mask out clouds.
And filtering by date first will reduce the number of images that you filter to your spatial extend.

```
var S2l2a = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .filterBounds(polys)
      .map(maskCloudsS2)
      .map(addTime)
      .map(addVI_S2)
```

This should be more efficient I think.